# DJANGO how to delete multiple records based on a field other than ID

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework and I need to delete multiple records based on the "contrato" field.

**View.py**

```
class AlugueisViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

   filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,DjangoFilterBackend)
   queryset = Alugueis.objects.all()
   serializer_class = AlugueisSerializer    
   filterset_fields = {           
        'contrato':['exact']            
   }
```

**Send**

Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/alugueis/?id=&contrato=174

Request Method: DELETE

Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed

Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000

Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Answer (score 0):

you can set `lookup_field` like below:

```
class AlugueisViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

   filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,DjangoFilterBackend)
   queryset = Alugueis.objects.all()
   serializer_class = AlugueisSerializer   
   filterset_fields = {           
        'contrato':['exact']            
   }
   lookup_field = 'contrato'
```

Comment: error DELETE: get() returned more than one Alugueis -- it returned 6!